# Filter nested array >=

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array like this:

```js
const rawdata = [
  {
    top_feature_col: "s9",
    top_feature_row: 1,
    data: [{ cluster: 0, value: 151508, opportunity_perc: 69 }]
  },
  {
    top_feature_col: "s9",
    top_feature_row: 2,
    data: [{ cluster: 0, value: 127518, opportunity_perc: 70 }]
  },
  {
    top_feature_col: "s9",
    top_feature_row: 2,
    data: [{ cluster: 1, value: 12668, opportunity_perc: 40 }]
  }
];
```

I'd like to filter where `opportunity_perc >= 50` but I don't know how to do it.

The result should be:

```js
const result = [
  {
    top_feature_col: "s9",
    top_feature_row: 1,
    data: [{ cluster: 0, value: 151508, opportunity_perc: 69 }]
  },
  {
    top_feature_col: "s9",
    top_feature_row: 2,
    data: [{ cluster: 0, value: 127518, opportunity_perc: 70 }]
  }
];
```

Comment: What will happen if any object in `data` array have `opportunity_perc` less than 50?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try with the `filter` method of `Array` class:

```js
const result = rawdata
    .filter(({data}) => data[0].opportunity_perc >= 50);
```

That will be valid if the `data` array will contains only one element (as per your example) if it's not you should specify in your request here what should be the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const rawdata = [
    {
        top_feature_col: "s9",
        top_feature_row: 1,
        data: [{cluster: 0, value: 151508, opportunity_perc: 69}]
    },
    {
        top_feature_col: "s9",
        top_feature_row: 2,
        data: [{cluster: 0, value: 127518, opportunity_perc: 70}]
    },
    {
        top_feature_col: "s9",
        top_feature_row: 2,
        data: [{cluster: 1, value: 12668, opportunity_perc: 40}]
    }
];

let filteredData = rawdata.filter((item) => {
    return ((item.data[0].opportunity_perc) >= 50);
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `filter` method with destructure and have the check with `opportunity_perc`

```js
const rawdata = [
  {
    top_feature_col: "s9",
    top_feature_row: 1,
    data: [{ cluster: 0, value: 151508, opportunity_perc: 69 }]
  },
  {
    top_feature_col: "s9",
    top_feature_row: 2,
    data: [{ cluster: 0, value: 127518, opportunity_perc: 70 }]
  },
  {
    top_feature_col: "s9",
    top_feature_row: 2,
    data: [{ cluster: 1, value: 12668, opportunity_perc: 40 }]
  }
];

const res = rawdata.filter(
  ({ data: [{ opportunity_perc }] }) => opportunity_perc >= 50
);

console.log(res);
```